# Should I edit a picture in a link?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, images

I have been noticing some people upload pictures and embed them in SO and others post a link to the picture in their posts.

What is the preferred way? Should you embed your pictures in SO or create links to your pictures?

If one way is preferred, should we edit posts and fix them to the preferred way of posting pictures?

Comment: I personally prefer few embedded pictures.  It's more convenient to read as long as you don't go overboard with too many images.

Comment: IIRC, you have to reach a certain level of reputation to embed pictures. I believe this is part of the [remove new user restrictions privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user). This is to prevent brand new users from posting screenshots of code and error messages. So a very new user is posting a link to their image because they can't embed it and someone with enough rep is doing it because they don't realize they can embed it.

Comment: The preferred method is to only supply an image when the problem cannot be adequately explained with typed code, typed error messages and/or typed sample data. The image should supplement this information, not replace it.

Comment: You need to stop this. You are flooding the queue with poor edits; you inline the picture but ignore all the other issues.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will make sure to address all issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to see how making people go to another site to see part of a question or answer would be better, so I always prefer inline images. I'd say edit posts that have links to images to either

1. put the image inline if it matters to the post, or
2. remove the link if it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you **do** inline the picture, be sure to give it a meaningful description. This not only helps people who use screen readers, it also helps everyone if the picture is for some reason not loading (some firewalls block it).

That being said, edits that only change a link to a picture are minor enough that it's wasteful to suggest edits that just do that. In many cases, I would rather add the one character myself (2k+ users can edit without review), **especially there are usually other errors that need to be fixed**.

To put this bluntly, the queue has been atypically large because you are **only** changing the picture to be inline. I am going to **reject** as many of these edits as I can because you are failing to fix the other issues present in each post.